# Invoking methods based on a string

Tags: c#, dictionary

I need to convert byte-arrays to different data types, such as `uint16` or `uint32`. The following class includes a dictionary filled with actions as the value in the `Dictionary` instance. Actions are `BitConverter.ToUInt16` or `BitConverter.ToUInt32`.

```
class DataTypes
{
    private Dictionary<string, Action> _dict;

    public DataTypes()
    {
        // create new dictionary
        _dict = new Dictionary<string, Action>();

        // fill dictionary with key-value pairs
        _dict.Add("uint16", BitConverter.ToUInt16);
        _dict.Add("uint32", BitConverter.ToUInt32);
        _dict.Add("sint16", BitConverter.ToInt16);
        _dict.Add("sint32", BitConverter.ToInt32);
    }

    // converts byte-array to specified type
    public object getValue(string type, byte[] data, int pos) // e.g. type = "uint16"
    {
        if (_dict.ContainsKey(type))
            return _dict[type](data, pos);
        return null;
    }
}
```

The above code does not run, because the compiler expects a method with 'void ToUInt32()' Signature (with braces).

Does anyone know how I could accomplish this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can rewrite it using the following:

```
    private Dictionary<string, Func<byte[], int, object>> _dict;

    public void DataTypes()
    {
        // create new dictionary
        _dict = new Dictionary<string, Func<byte[], int, object>>
        {
            // fill dictionary with key-value pairs
            {"uint16", (data, pos) => BitConverter.ToUInt16(data, pos)},
            {"uint32", (data, pos) => BitConverter.ToUInt32(data, pos)},
            {"sint16", (data, pos) => BitConverter.ToInt16(data, pos)},
            {"sint32", (data, pos) => BitConverter.ToInt32(data, pos)}
        };
    }

    // converts byte-array to specified type
    public object getValue(string type, byte[] data, int pos) // e.g. type = "uint16"
    {
        if (_dict.ContainsKey(type))
            return _dict[type](data, pos);
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: @Boozzz if that solution is ok then you should mark it as an answer

Answer (score 2):

Agumenting [Ivan Zub's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26253883/91696): you don't need to recreate the dictionary every time you instantiate the class, you can place the dictionary in a static field.

```
public class DataTypes
{
    private static readonly IReadOnlyDictionary<string, Func<IEnumerable<byte>, int, object>> Converters;

    static DataTypes()
    {
        Converters =
            new ReadOnlyDictionary<string, Func<IEnumerable<byte>, int, object>>(
                new Dictionary<string, Func<IEnumerable<byte>, int, object>>
                {
                    { "System.UInt16", (value, startIndex) => BitConverter.ToUInt16(value.ToArray(), startIndex) },
                    { "System.UInt32", (value, startIndex) => BitConverter.ToUInt32(value.ToArray(), startIndex) },
                    { "System.Int16", (value, startIndex) => BitConverter.ToInt16(value.ToArray(), startIndex) },
                    { "System.Int32", (value, startIndex) => BitConverter.ToInt32(value.ToArray(), startIndex) }
                });
    }

    public object GetValue(string type, byte[] value, int startIndex)
    {
        if (!Converters.ContainsKey(type))
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("type");
        }

        return Converters[type](value, startIndex);
    }
}
```

And if the class has no other methods (or they don't depend on internal state), you can make both the class and `GetValue` static too.

Comment: This throughs me a `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` in the last code line (`Converters[type](value, startIndex);`) when parameter `type="uint16"`, `value` is a `byte[80]`, and `startIndex = 50`.

Comment: Check your debugger, are you sure it's not `throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("type");` who is throwing? Do note that I'm using the [fully qualified names](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dfb3cx8s(v=vs.71).aspx) for the dictionary keys.